# Any way to run Java as a service while still being able to send Commands to the console?

Tags: windows, java, service

I have a Java program which run in the Java console that I would like to run as a service. This, on its own, is not a big problem as I could use something like `YAJSW` (Yet Another Java Service Wrapper).

The problem lies in that I need to lock the database files before backup runs and unlock the database files after backup completes, which can only be done through the Java Console via commands. Currently, this java program is running on a Linux server where I can access the Java Console via `tmux` to automate the backup process. But due to various reasons, I am looking to get rid of this server.

So in short; I would like to know if anyone knows of a way to run java process as a service on Windows, but still be able send commands to the console. This could be by calling the wrapper with a parameter or something like that. I don’t care about the console output. In the rare instances that I need this output, I am completely fine with having to stop the service and run it in a manual process. I just need to send commands to the console of the Java console to automate the backup process.

Any ideas? I don’t seem to be able to find any way to do this.